# Posting an answer to your own off topic questions

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer

I flagged a post for a question that was off-topic and the flag for closure was accepted but the question remains open, then for some reason I thought of checking out the OP's question history, 3 out of 5 questions are in the same format, asking how to do something that -to me- is off-topic according to SO's policies. I want to flag these questions, but I'm concerned they're gonna remain open just like the first one I flagged.

I know that answering your own questions can be encouraged if there's no one to answer it for you, and with time you come up with the answer for it. But I'm worried about the amounts of questions like these that get through and remain on the site.

Comment: Honestly, not much you can do. But rest assured that some members of the community looked at it, and some sort of action was taken (even if it is not the one that you immediately wanted).

Comment: Expecting somebody else to take care of it can be disappointing, especially when the Q+A is old.  You have enough rep, you should use it.  Just downvote both the question and the answer.  The OP gets the hint loud and clear.

Comment: Questions are not even that old tho, oldest one is from October. I did comment in the latest question telling him the question seems to be off-topic, but I haven't got a reply from this user. @HansPassant

Comment: I know mods can look at my flagging history, that's why I decided to hide said user's profile. I'm not a big fan of meta effect. I trust those that work in the shadows, I believe this post is good enough for that @Zizouz212

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton no one except mods can see your flags.  I know it sucks to be the source of the meta effect on a post, if you want to see them closed, you'll have to give us some more info.

Comment: Only moderators have the ability to look at any flagging history. And even then, they don't do it. With thousands of flags a day, I bet you have the mods here don't call out users for their flags :)

Comment: A question that's a day old is old.  There's another 12,000 every day, users don't dwell on what happened in October.  You have the tools, use them.

Comment: So you're saying I should link them? @psubsee2003

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton depends on your goal of this post.  If you want to understand what to do, then no.  But if you had other motives....

Comment: I agree with using the downvote and I will usually comment so the OP knows why there are downvotes. Particularly in one instance (yesterday) where the Op kept posting the same question repeatedly and then did a self answer on the last one, with the answer taken from a previous answer to the first question of the series of dups.

Comment: Other motives? You were the one asking for *"more info"* please don't take me for someone who enjoys the meta effect @psubsee2003